# WiFi Problems with Ubuntu MATE

Tags: 16.04, wireless, mate

I’ve been having trouble getting WiFi to work reliably on my laptop with Ubuntu 16.04.3 and MATE 1.12.1. I can connect to the network, but Firefox and the terminal both time out whenever I try to do anything, despite System Moniter showing that I am transmitting and receiving (tiny) amounts of data. Occasionally itll suddenly start working again for a minute or two before stopping again. I don’t think it’s my router, as my phone works fine, but Ethernet works fine. Does anyone know what this is and how to fix it?

Comment: Use the command `lshw` to determine the *exact* model of your wireless hardware.  Search AskUbuntu for other threads related to that exact model number. Then please mark your thread as a duplicate of the one that solves your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.